# Cannot get this Function to work it is something wrong with the Loop I think

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason this produces a value error.  The function is supposed to tell me what sheet the value is on it worked fine until I added the `T` variable loop.  I know I am missing something simple.

```
Function FIND_THE_ENTRY(x) As String
    Dim lngBottom As Long
    For Each element In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'loops every worksheet
        lngBottom = Sheets(element.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For T = 1 To 26 'why does this not work
            For R = 1 To lngBottom
                If Sheets(element.Name).Cells(R, T).Value = x Then
                    FIND_THE_ENTRY = FIND_THE_ENTRY & element.Name & ", "
                End If
            Next R
        Next T
    Next element

    FIND_THE_ENTRY = Left(FIND_THE_ENTRY, Len(FIND_THE_ENTRY) - 2)
End Function
```

Comment: `'Next element` is causing too many nexts. Delete that row.

Comment: @tbur `For Each element In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`...`next element` is just looping through the worksheets in the activeworkbook. It can't find more worksheets than actually exist.

Comment: Where is the error occuring? Which line is it erroring on? I could see it erroring on the last line if FIND_THE_ENTRY is not filled, but other than that, everything looks fine (assuming that there are always values in Column A of each sheet that is being searched.

Comment: @JNevill: Oops, I didn't copy all of the code. :(  OP, I ran the code over several sheets with success. There is always the chance a sheet will have nothing in Column A. Which would make the last row, Row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through rows and columns and performing a test on every cell can be expensive and should be avoided where possible (often times it's not, obviously). In this case, I believe you could write this using the `.find` method of the `range`. This will get you out of your loop, which is dependent on finding the last row that contains data in Column A and gets you out of slowly creeping through each cell looking for X.

```
Function FIND_THE_ENTRY(x) As String
    Dim lngBottom As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Element as Worksheet
    For Each Element In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'loops every worksheet
        With Element.Range("A1:Z1000000")
            Set rng = .Find(What:=x, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
        End With
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            FIND_THE_ENTRY = FIND_THE_ENTRY & Element.Name & ", "
        End If
    Next Element

    FIND_THE_ENTRY = Left(FIND_THE_ENTRY, Len(FIND_THE_ENTRY) - 2)
End Function
```

Honestly, I didn't see anything wrong with your code besides the fact that trying to determine `Left(FIND_THE_ENTRY, LENGTH(FIND_THE_ENTRY)- 2)` will throw a big fat error if `FIND_THE_ENTRY` is `vbnull` and there are a couple of things that could cause it to be null like not finding X in any worksheet and not having values in every populated row of Column A of each worksheet.